# Stylesheets and scripts not loading

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

```
function spartans_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('mybootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/mybootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/spartanscripts.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/custom.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('GoogleFonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
    wp_enqueue_style('editor-styles', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/editor-style.css');


    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/mybootstrap.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');


    // wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcdn', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

 }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spartans_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `. '/style.css'` to you first enqueue to actually load that file. Also, depending on your server's settings you may encounter problems with loading edited versions of your style sheets if you don't include a version number as the fourth parameter to [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Finally, you may want to check your code whether you are [registering](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) the same handles with different parameters elsewhere (for instance in a parent theme). If they are registered first with a dependency (third parameter) and that file isn't loaded, then these will not enqueue either.